# How to generate view, after click on treelist node in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, treelist

I have a **Extjs** project and files is as follows:

**app:**

-> view -> main -> MainController.js

-> view -> categories -> CategoriesController.js

**classic:**

-> view

-> main -> Main.js

->categories -> Categories.js

And I use treelist to this.

Now, I want when user click on treelist nodes a generate view. for example: When click on category node, generate Category.js view.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the downloaded extjs zip. There is a template folder with an admin dashboard and an executive dashboard. Or read the guides in the docs. But you can configure your center region of the viewport as a card layout and activate views for it..

Comment: Excuse me, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate a listener to the `treelist` to handle the users's click event (on the view that includes the `treelist`). You can listen the `selectionchange` event.

```
{
  xtype: 'treelist',
  store: 'NavigationTree',
  listeners: {
    selectionchange: 'onNavigationTreeSelectionChange'
  }
}
```

On the `onNavigationTreeSelectionChange` handler (on the view controller), you need to create the new view, based on the clicked node properties. Something like:

```
onNavigationTreeSelectionChange: function (tree, node) {
    console.log('onNavigationTreeSelectionChange');
    var tp = this.getPlanPresentationBar();
    var newView;
    if (node && node.get('extjsview')) {
        switch (node.get('extjsview')) {
            case 'Category':
                newView = new MyApp.view.Category({});
                break;
            case 'sync.Sync':
                newView = new MyApp.view.sync.Sync({});
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        tp.add(newView);
    }
},
```

Is this example, we use the property `extjsview` of the node to know which view to create (if check if the user clicked the Category node).  In the example code, the newView is added to an existing tabpanel, but it really depends on the rest of your application.

As already mentioned by [Tarabass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408487/tarabass), you should check the [Dashboard example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard).